# Plot data from mat file using plot_surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mat

I want to plot a 3d plot from a mat file. Here is my code:

```
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mat=scipy.io.loadmat('data.mat')

mat_data = mat['data']
print(mat_data)

Xcoor = []
Ycoor = []
Zcoor = []


for x in mat_data:
    Xcoor.append(x[0])
    Ycoor.append(x[1])
    Zcoor.append(x[2])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(Xcoor, Ycoor, Zcoor)

plt.show()
```

But when I try to run this code i get an error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:/PycharmProjects/Munpy/fromMat.py", line 44, in <module>
>     ax.plot_surface(wspX, wspY, wspZ)   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line
> 1609, in plot_surface
>     if Z.ndim != 2: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

What should I do with my Zcoor for this to work? The mat_data is in this format:

```
[[x1 y1 z1]
[x2 y2 z2]
...
[xn yn zn]]
```

Comment: `plot_surface` requires 2D arrays as input, not 1D lists.

Comment: How should I load this data then? Its works fine when i do this:

`X,Y = np.meshgrid(Xcoor, Ycoor)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

ax.plot_surface(Xcoor, Ycoor, Z)`

Comment: It appears strange that `ax.plot_surface(Xcoor, Ycoor, Z)` should work correctly, since that would suggest that you have no doubled coordinates in your matrix (that it is in fact rather a line than a surface). In any case without further knowledge about the data in use here, one may indeed close this as duplicate of the most general case of non, uniform, unordered coordinates.